# C# Math.pow(x, 0.333)

Tags: c#, math, nan, pow

```
private double f(double x, double zn = 1)
    {
        double X = - zn;
        X *= x * x * (x + 1);
        X *= Math.Pow((x - 2), 0.333);
        return funct ? x : X;
    }
```

I have this code. When I try to find Math.Pow((x-2), 0.333) - i have NaN.
How to solve it? Why NaN?

Rewritten...

```
private double f(double x, double zn = 1)
    {
        double answer = - zn;
        answer *= x * x * (x + 1);
        answer *= Math.Pow((x - 2), 0.333);
        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: What parameter values did you use? (what are `x`and `zn`?)

Comment: It's happening with all parameter values?

Comment: @HansKesting zn is defaulted at 1, but an example of x would be nice.

Comment: Perhaps `x` is less than 2.0.

Comment: x is an argument of function.
zn - positive or negative function returns

Comment: note that if you want to get the cube root then `Math.pow(x, 0.333)` is a very bad idea. `0.333` is no where near 1/3 in double precision[

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that you're taking the cube root of a negative number. That seems the most likely cause, but your code is *really* hard to read due to having both `x` and `X` as local variables...

After closer examination, as you're not actually modifying `x` at any point, it really depends on the incoming value of `x`. If it's a finite value greater than or equal to 2, it should be fine. But if `x` is smaller than 2, it will fail (well, return NaN) for reasons of simple maths...

Comment: hmm... 
How to write it, when number is less than 2?

Comment: @lis.sanLee: That's impossible to say when we don't know the purpose of your code.

Comment: I find solve of this problem. I use Math.Abs(x-2), and then multiplied by the number sign.
Thx for help

Answer (score 9):

You can see there all 3 cases when Math.Pow returns NaN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

> public static double Pow(double x, double y)

1) x or y = NaN.

2) x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity.

3) x = -1; y = NegativeInfinity or PositiveInfinity.

Answer (score 1):

[Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) is not defined for numbers less than 0 for given power. So you function will fail for some x.

> x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity.
>   Result: NaN

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) it explains all the situations where Math.Pow will give NaN. I suspect this case may be your problem:

```
x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity.
```